# sync folder from docker container to host during build

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I'm trying to setup a php simple image to act as base for my app and I can use it with several services i.e. nginx, redis .. etc

I have the below Docker file

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=8.1.9

FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-cli-alpine

# ARG PECL_OPENSWOOLE_VERSION=4.11.1

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache \
    supervisor \
    tree \
    vim \
    --update linux-headers \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear

# supervisord setup
RUN mkdir -p /etc/supervisor/ \
    && mkdir -p /var/log/supervisord/
COPY docker/dev/php-cli/config/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer


COPY . /srv/www/
WORKDIR /srv/www
RUN mkdir -p vendor
RUN chown -R www-data: /srv/www

USER www-data
RUN composer validate --strict 
RUN composer install

USER root
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

I have this directory structure of the project

```bash
├── Makefile
├── bin
│   └── console
├── composer.json
├── config
├── docker
│   └── dev
│       ├── nginx
│       │   └── app.conf
│       └── php-cli
│           ├── Dockerfile
│           └── config
│               └── supervisord.conf
├── docker-compose.yaml
└── src
    └── user.php
```

also the contents of `docker-composer.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/dev/php-cli/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/www/
```

After i run, `docker-composer up --build`, I don't see the vendor folder created on the host machine nor I can find on the docker container and application fail to run.

What I'm trying to achieve is an empty project and have it setup and packages installed while building.

What am I doing wrong ?

I tried several scenarios of the `Dockerfile` and the `docker-compose.yaml` but with no success.

Comment: A Dockerfile can never create files on the host.  Does it work to delete the `volumes:` block, and have the container run the code in the application, without needing a duplicate copy of it on the host?

Comment: you are correct, but how can I achieve what I want? basically I would like to have the vendor folder present on the host machine after the docker service is started and installed everything